# cannnot boot to text mode with r/w fileystem

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, grub2, text-mode

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 server to a laptop, and the grub file is along the lines of:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
    gfxmod $linux -gfxmod
    set root ='hd0,msdos/'

    if[[x%feature_platform_search_hint=xy];then
        search --nofloppy ...
        ...

        else
            search -- noflopppy ...
    fi

linux /vmliuz -3.5.0-17 ??? root = /dev/map/dur2\-root ro
initrd /initrd...
```

(pardon, that was written by pencil and not complete, obviously).

How can I put something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` in there to boot to text mode?

Or, is there another way to boot to text mode with a live, editable file system using GRUB?

Comment: apparently change the linux line to:  `linux /vmliuz -3.5.0-17 ??? root = /dev/map/dur2\-root ro text`  will do the trick.  (geoft on #grub freenode irc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question.  You set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text" in /etc/default/grub, then run `sudo update-grub`.